# GraphQL subscription does not receive messages after successful handshake

Tags: node.js, websocket, nestjs, apollo-server, graphql-subscriptions

I have created a simple `GraphQL Subscription` using `Nest.js/Apollo GraphQL` over `Node.js`. My client application which is a `react.js/apollo client` works find with the server. The client subscibes to the server via GraphQL similar to:

```
subscription
{
    studentAdded
    {
        id
    }
}
```

My problem is that it works only locally. When I deploy my server back-end to a hosted docker over internet, client won't receive data anymore.
I have traced the client, it sends GET request on ws://api.example.com:8010/graphql and receives the successful HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols response. However, nothing is received from server like when the server was on my local machine. Checking the remote server log showed me that the client successfully connects to server. There, I can see `onConnect` log messages.

Now I need any guidance to solve the problem.

I check several things myself. Firstly, I thought WebSocket address is prohibited in the network but then realized that it is on same port as normal HTTP. Secondly, supposed that WebSocket messages/frames are transmitted over UDP but I was not correct, it is over TCP and no need to worry about network settings.

Additionally I have read several github threads and StackOverflow questions. But did not find any clue. I am not directly using Node.js/WebSocket, instead, I am using Nest.js/GraphqQL subscription. It has made my search tougher.

Your help is highly appreciated.

Comment: @Afsher did you get a solution for this? im facing the same issue

Comment: @phainix It was just a stupid bug in deployment. Connection strings were not passed correctly to the production environment.

Comment: Alright, thank you!